# Click on profile from feed - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I have a feed that is showing posts from the users that wanted to post something. What I am trying to do is display the name of the user that posted something in a button (that is working). Then when a user is pressing that button it should show another viewcontroller with the name of the button that the user pressed (that is semi-working).

What happens now is, when a user is pressing the name of another user from the post, the name that is showing in the other viewcontroller is not always the same as the name the user pressed.

I hope you understand :-)

Let me walk you through my code:

**First viewController**
before viewDidLoad, I am creating a string:

```
var sendName = "No name recieved"
```

Further down the page is this code:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell:updateTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! updateTableViewCell
            let update = updates[indexPath.row]

        cell.nameButton.setTitle(update.addedByUser, forState: .Normal)
        sendName = (cell.nameButton.titleLabel?.text)!

}
```

My prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if(segue.identifier == "showProfileFromFeed") {

            let yourNextViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as! profileTableViewController)
            yourNextViewController.viaSegue = sendName
        }
    }
```

The button title is being changed to what it should in the feed, but there must be something wrong with sendName because it doesn't always show the same name on the other viewController as the buttonTitle says..

Hope you can understand, otherwise please let me know :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that where you update the `sendName` variable is the problem. The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called whenever a new cell is about to be displayed, or when the table is redrawn.

I don't know exactly how your app works, but if you can have multiple posts on the screen at the same time, then this means that the `sendName` variable would only be correct if you were pressing the button for the bottom-most post.

If you pressed the button for any other post then you would still get the name of the bottom-most post.

What I would recommend is using an IBAction that is triggered when the button is clicked to change the `sendName` variable. Then you can manually initiate the segue.

Comment: I believe that is the problem too, after I added a print() function - that is also what I found out.. I just do not know how to do it correctly, so that the name I'm pressing is the one that is being send to the next viewController?

Comment: I guess if you are creating the buttons programmatically, then you will have to add a target to the button, which is linked to a custom function that you create. The function can then define the `sendName` variable and then initiate the segue. You might have to look up some of this on SO to really accomplish your goal, but hopefully this gives you an idea of what to do.